# Why does the browser skip a blank title?

Tags: javascript, html

If I have an HTML file, `file.html`, which contains:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
document.title="";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

the title is set to `file.html` (because of the void title). But if I have something like:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
document.title="title";
document.title="";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

the title is now set to `title`. Why not `file.html`?

Comment: [No-repro.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/HN5Ek/show/) Which browser are you using?

Comment: Can't reproduce this either using Firefox 16.0.2

Comment: @minitech In chrome your repro has title of title rather than blank.

Comment: @MartinSmith: But I'm using Chrome :'( Which version? (25 here)

Comment: it seems it has a different behavior on various browsers. in IE 9 it's ok. In Chrome 22.0.1229.94 no.

Comment: To begin with, are you sure the script is even executed? According to the [W3C definition of the script tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html) for HTML4, the `type` attribute is required and has no default (but that depends on browser implementation). Since you also specify no doctype, HTML4 may be what the browser assumes. Try an alert() to see if it works.

Comment: @minitech `23.0.1271.64`. [screenshot here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0ug3O.png)

Comment: @Mario De Schaepmeester yes, it's executed.

Comment: @Mario: Browsers usually just assume JS or whatever their ES engine is if the `type` isn't there.

Comment: I think it's a bug, then. (Possibly [this one](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=96846&can=1&q=%22document.title%22&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20OS%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary&start=300) again? Not sure.)